# Can't call fetch when a prop changes

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I have a component that takes year as a prop and must fetch some data for that year and render based on the data.

```
export let year;

onMount(async()=>{
    data = await fetchData(year);
})

{#each data as d}
    <Child d={d}></Child>
{/each}
```

The prop year changes dynamically in the parent of this component (based on a dropdown). I want to fetch data every time the variable year changes.

The above code doesn't work because onMount is called only when the component is first rendered.

I tried using beforeUpdate, but that causes an infinite loop. Since the data changes inside beforeUpdate, it triggers another update.

If I try something like
`$: fetchData(year)`

it gives me this error

> "Error: Cannot call `fetch` eagerly during server side rendering with relative URL — put your `fetch` calls inside `onMount` or a `load` function instead."

Is there a way to listen to changes only on the variable year and call fetch when it changes?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the [key](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#key) logic block.

In the parent I did

```
{#key year}
    <Component year={year}/>
{/key}
```

I know this doesn't entirely answer the question, but it fixes the problem. If someone knows how to actually call fetch when a prop is updated, please answer. Thank you.